# Assign new user programmatically to the group defined in Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

My goal is to assign programmatically a new user to the group (*Posts*->*Categories*) defined in Wordpress. I want to achieve it by Wordpress REST API or directly modifying database table. Looking on Google, couldn't find plugin or API to achieve this.

I have a low-level, among other normal, users in Wordpress and category related to them, where they can make posts and Administrator will review and eventually publish them.
Whenever a new user is being created in my system, I want to assign them to the specific category in Wordpress.

What is the possible way to achieve this? By writing own plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution to this issue: direct INSERT to the Wordpress MySQL Database:

```
insert into wp_newsletter (email, token, status, created, List_1 , list_2, list_3, list_4)
VALUES('name@email.com', SUBSTR(md5(randomNumbers), 1, 10), 'C', CURDATE(), 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

This will assign the user to groups. Table `wp_newsletter` is being used by the plugin *Newsletter*